# Undesired background color overlay while using brunch/with-react

Tags: reactjs, brunch

I am not sure this issue is related directly to brunch, but it's the first time I use this framework and first time I see something like this ...

I am trying out brunch/with-react skeleton and there is a little issue with my DOM elements.

I changed my body's background color as follow, in `app/styles/application.css`

```
body {
  background-color: #cfcfcf
}
```

Here is the result
[DOM rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdTjI.png)

I am using Chrome so I went ahead and inspected every elements. 
I cannot find any element responsible for this behavior.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your html?

Comment: Related files in a gist  here : https://gist.github.com/alexishuard/465bf6cf826f2c1c082837ca70d479f2

Answer (score 0):

Your html pages says:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app.css">
```

But your css filename is application.css

Comment: This is how brunch compiles all the css in public/app.css ; so application.css was actually compiled in the appropriate file.